# Youtube Control Bar Blurry

Tags: youtube, flash

I am using Chrome on Windows 7 Ultimate x64, desktop computer
I have adobe flash 11.8.800.168 installed, the latest one. I have already disabled Chrome's built in flash player.

However, my youtube control bar (timestamp, play/pause, volume, quality) is blurry when I play the video in full screen, I can change the quality of the video and it works fine, but the control bar seems to be using 360 resolution enlarged.

Here is a picture [image]

and as you can see, it is in HD, full screen, but they are very blurry.

I tried doing Google search and tried lots of different keywords, but wasn't able to find an answer.I remember having this issue on my laptop, which I was able to fix by playing around with hardware acceleration. But not this time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked with any other browsers?

Comment: I have checked with IE, it works fine, but I have been using chrome for a long time and was hoping for a fix.

Comment: I expect it's a browser-dependent issue, then.

Comment: I remember that sometimes hardware acceleration (a graphics / display issue) morphed some things on youtube, in Firefox. You might also have disabled the Adobe Flash's acceleration. Maybe these might be better solutions, but as I don't have a way to replicate the problem I won't write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys I found a fix for this, there are 2 ways.

1. Get the **jwplayer** plug in for chrome, you can simply just google that and you can install the plug in.
2. This was what I did, my resolution was on 16:9, so I am not sure about people on other ratios, but if your ratio is **16:9**, this should work. Open up a video, leave it there (dont full screen). Go to your video settings, change your resolution to something **4:3**, for example **640 * 480**. Now in this resolution, full screen the video, while it is full screened, **alt-tab** away (so that the player is still full screened in the background), go back to your settings and change it back to your native resolution. And that should do the trick.